# Dynamic variable and Async

Tags: java, android, opencv, asynchronous

I have a variable called grayVal, it tells me the grayscale value of a pixel  what my camera is being pointed at. Obviously this number is constantly changing when I move the camera around. My Issue is that when I pass grayVal in an async with a loop to test how long it takes for grayVal to pass a threshold, the number never changes no matter what I point the camera at. Is this a limit of async and I need to do another solution?

```
public class startTestAsync extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> {
    double[] timeArray = new double[500]; // set array
    double rating = 0;
    double lagStartTime;
    double lagEndTime;
    double lagTimeResult;
    int testAmount;
    int cnt;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Integer...grayVal) {
        for (testAmount = 0; testAmount < 500; testAmount++) {
            Log.i("Mat Value", String.valueOf(grayVal[0]));
            lagStartTime = System.nanoTime();
            while (grayVal[0] <= 100) {
                lagEndTime = System.nanoTime();
                lagTimeResult = (lagEndTime - lagStartTime);
                timeArray[testAmount] = lagTimeResult;
         }
         return null;
 }
 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
 }
```

ui thread

```
public void startTest (View view) {
    new startTestAsync().execute(grayVal);
}

@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    grayMat = inputFrame.gray();
    double[] grayPixel = grayMat.get(100,100);
    grayVal = (int)grayPixel[0];
    Log.i("Mat Value", String.valueOf(grayVal));
    return grayMat;
}
```

grayVal in onCameraFrame logcat

```
08-25 08:28:56.576  14645-14989/bluemage.systems.displaylatencytester I/Mat Value﹕ 50
08-25 08:28:56.639  14645-14989/bluemage.systems.displaylatencytester I/Mat Value﹕ 37
08-25 08:28:56.703  14645-14989/bluemage.systems.displaylatencytester I/Mat Value﹕ 52
08-25 08:28:56.769  14645-14989/bluemage.systems.displaylatencytester I/Mat Value﹕ 53
08-25 08:28:56.835  14645-14989/bluemage.systems.displaylatencytester I/Mat Value﹕ 50
08-25 08:28:56.903  14645-14989/bluemage.systems.displaylatencytester I/Mat Value﹕ 48
08-25 08:28:56.971  14645-14989/bluemage.systems.displaylatencytester I/Mat Value﹕ 47
08-25 08:28:57.038  14645-14989/bluemage.systems.displaylatencytester I/Mat Value﹕ 49
08-25 08:28:57.103  14645-14989/bluemage.systems.displaylatencytester I/Mat Value﹕ 46
08-25 08:28:57.172  14645-14989/bluemage.systems.displaylatencytester I/Mat Value﹕ 46
08-25 08:28:57.240  14645-14989/bluemage.systems.displaylatencytester I/Mat Value﹕ 43
08-25 08:28:57.302  14645-14989/bluemage.systems.displaylatencytester I/Mat Value﹕ 41
08-25 08:28:57.368  14645-14989/bluemage.systems.displaylatencytester I/Mat Value﹕ 44
08-25 08:28:57.436  14645-14989/bluemage.systems.displaylatencytester I/Mat Value﹕ 46
```

grayVal in Async logcat

```
08-25 08:32:01.111  20759-21076/bluemage.systems.displaylatencytester I/Mat Value﹕ 133
08-25 08:32:01.111  20759-21076/bluemage.systems.displaylatencytester I/Mat Value﹕ 133
08-25 08:32:01.111  20759-21076/bluemage.systems.displaylatencytester I/Mat Value﹕ 133
08-25 08:32:01.111  20759-21076/bluemage.systems.displaylatencytester I/Mat Value﹕ 133
08-25 08:32:01.112  20759-21076/bluemage.systems.displaylatencytester I/Mat Value﹕ 133
08-25 08:32:01.112  20759-21076/bluemage.systems.displaylatencytester I/Mat Value﹕ 133
08-25 08:32:01.112  20759-21076/bluemage.systems.displaylatencytester I/Mat Value﹕ 133
08-25 08:32:01.112  20759-21076/bluemage.systems.displaylatencytester I/Mat Value﹕ 133
08-25 08:32:01.114  20759-21076/bluemage.systems.displaylatencytester I/Mat Value﹕ 133
08-25 08:32:01.114  20759-21076/bluemage.systems.displaylatencytester I/Mat Value﹕ 133
08-25 08:32:01.114  20759-21076/bluemage.systems.displaylatencytester I/Mat Value﹕ 133
08-25 08:32:01.114  20759-21076/bluemage.systems.displaylatencytester I/Mat Value﹕ 133
08-25 08:32:01.114  20759-21076/bluemage.systems.displaylatencytester I/Mat Value﹕ 133
08-25 08:32:01.114  20759-21076/bluemage.systems.displaylatencytester I/Mat Value﹕ 133
08-25 08:32:01.114  20759-21076/bluemage.systems.displaylatencytester I/Mat Value﹕ 133
```

both grayVal in logat

```
08-25 09:02:49.170    6402-7189/bluemage.systems.displaylatencytester I/Mat Value Async﹕ 23
08-25 09:02:49.170    6402-7189/bluemage.systems.displaylatencytester I/Mat Value Async﹕ 23
08-25 09:02:49.170    6402-7189/bluemage.systems.displaylatencytester I/Mat Value Async﹕ 23
08-25 09:02:49.170    6402-6843/bluemage.systems.displaylatencytester I/Mat Value﹕ 22
08-25 09:02:49.170    6402-7189/bluemage.systems.displaylatencytester I/Mat Value Async﹕ 23
08-25 09:02:49.170    6402-7189/bluemage.systems.displaylatencytester I/Mat Value Async﹕ 23
```

Comment: What makes you think that `grayVal` should change its value? Is there some code that you are not showing here; that runs in a different thread and that **changes** the content of that array? You see - unless some other piece of code **changes** a variable ... just reading it will always return the same values?!

Comment: onCameraFrame changes `grayVal`

Comment: If it does; why do the values not change?! Maybe you should provide some code where "grayVal" is actually changing?

Comment: added onCameraFrame and Async logcats

Comment: So, obviously, you are doing: `grayMat = inputFrame.gray(); double[] grayPixel = grayMat.get(100,100);` I guess this code retrieves a reference to an array, which is then continuously updated. So, the interesting question is: where is the code that turns such a `grayPixel` array ... into a parameter for `doInBackground()`?! Most likely, that is where things break apart ...

Comment: is grayVal an array or a primitive type (you access it differently)? Is it volatile?

Comment: grayVal = (int)grayPixel[0];

Comment: so what should `grayVal[0] <= 100` do?

Comment: greayVal is a volatile int

Comment: In your logfiles you should compare overlapping timestamps... values before time `08-25 08:28:57.436` doesn't tell you anything about values after time `08-25 08:32:01.111` ... it would be interesting whether value 133 appears in the first logfile or not

Comment: `grayVal[0] <= 100` checks to see the value is over 100, and if it is then gets the time for the calculation

Comment: http://pastebin.com/L9qQhqYM the logcat that shows the async and ui thred grayval

Comment: shouldn't that be `grayVal <= 100` or is grayVal an array in that context after all?

Comment: what happens if you change to `grayVal[0] = (int)grayPixel[0]; Log.i("Mat Value", String.valueOf(grayVal[0]));`

Comment: android studio says `array type expected, found int`

Comment: and if you change to `while (grayVal <= 100)` ? Do you see that in your code, once grayVal is accessed like an array and once it is accessed like an integer? What's wrong there? Can you add your current complete code like you did yesterday (you added a pastebin link)?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/4iu4kBvb

Answer (score 1):

`grayVal` (in `doInBackground`)  and `grayVal` ( in `onCameraFrame`) are different 
variables thus changes in one do not reflect on the other.

Even not having your full code it is possible to conclude that they are different variables because they have different incompatible types.

`grayVal` (in `doInBackground`) is an array as can be deduced from this code :

```
        Log.i("Mat Value", String.valueOf(grayVal[0]));
        lagStartTime = System.nanoTime();
        while (grayVal[0] <= 100) {
```

`grayVal` ( in `onCameraFrame`) is of primitive type (or its wrapper class) as can be deduced from this code :

```
grayVal = (int)grayPixel[0];
```

Comment: How would I reflect the grayVal ( in onCameraFrame) changes to the grayVal (in doInBackground)

Comment: can you look at my code and point me in the right direction? http://pastebin.com/tZkFbJUZ